# SIMPLE :: XCOPY NOT PRODUCING OUTPUT IN .bat

Tags: batch-file, copy, windows-xp, xcopy

I'm a mortgage loan guy in Seattle, WA and I frequently set up a folder hierarchy into which I save a client's documents and as they come in to me.  I've been creating these manually for years and I'd like to save the 3 to 4 minutes it takes to set these up by using a batch file.

So...  I have a default set of folders, some of which contain a couple of small Adobe PDFs.  What I'd like to do (and cannot make happen) is to run a batch file that would facilitate some custom remarks or input from me during the batch so that with a click and a couple of keystrokes, I have an organized folder setup for a new client within seconds rather than minutes.

I've written the following but it isn't producing any output folders or files.

______not sure character terms show correctly - see linked images below for actual______

```
@echo off
::Ask
echo Your Source Path:
set INPUT1=
set /P INPUT1=Type input:

echo Your Destination Path:
set INPUT2=
set /P INPUT2=Type input: 

C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe /e /v %INPUT1% %INPUT2%
```

---

My responses were:

to the first prompt `"E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\002 ATLAS\ATLAS RESOURCES\000NEWCLIENTFOLDER2014"`
to the second prompt `"E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\001 CLIENTS\"`

I have verified that xcopy.exe is in fact located as indicated above.

I'm on XP SP3

My actual paths and .bat file are shown in the linked image for clarity.

http://www.avidrecording.com/images/01.png

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Rem save this as a .bat file and run
@echo off
set /P source=Enter Source Folder:
echo %Source%
set /P destination=Enter Destination Folder:
echo %destination%
xcopy %source% %destination% /v /i /e
```

Comment: Like this???@echo off
::Ask
echo Your Source Path:
set INPUT1=
set /P INPUT1=Type input: "E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\002 ATLAS\ATLAS RESOURCES\000NEWCLIENTFOLDER2014"

echo Your Destination Path:
set INPUT2=
set /P INPUT2=Type input: "E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\001 CLIENTS\"

C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe %INPUT1% %INPUT2% /e /v

Comment: Yes and your set /P should be just: set /P Var_Name=Prompt_Message

Comment: I have it like this and it still doesn't work.  
http://www.avidrecording.com/images/02.png

Comment: Rem save this as a .bat file and run
echo off
set /P source=Enter Source Folder:
echo %Source%
set /P destination=Enter Destination Folder:
echo %destination%
xcopy %source% %destination% /v /i /e

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your problem appears to be that the `xcopy` command can't figure out which of the data it is receiving is parameters and which switches and which superfluous because you have spaces in your directorynames.

Fortunately, the cure is simple. `"quote your parameters"`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe /e /v "%INPUT1%" "%INPUT2%"
```

Now - the path to `xcopy.exe` is probably superfluous - as is the extension, so

```
xcopy /e /v "%INPUT1%" "%INPUT2%"
```

is more than likely all you'd need.

(I'd caution to experiment with a throw-away destination until you've perfected your method. I use a RAMDISK...)

Also, if you're copying a template, then there's no apparent reason for all the folderol about inputting `Input1`. If you have more than one template set, set up a separate batch and shortcut  for each one with a fixed template path, eg

```
xcopy /e /v "E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\002 ATLAS\ATLAS RESOURCES\000NEWCLIENTFOLDER2014" "%INPUT2%"
```

Note the use of quotes to defeat the evil spaces.

Next, your destination could be built, but may contain spaces. For instance, you may have a client to which you wish to refer as "037 - Fred Nurk". Now it's a pain to have to type in the full path, so make it easy. Just type in the `037 - Fred Nurk` part and let batch fill in the rest.

```
xcopy /e /v "E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\002 ATLAS\ATLAS RESOURCES\000NEWCLIENTFOLDER2014" "E:\DV8333 MY DOCUMENTS\001 CLIENTS"\"%input2%"\
```

Note that this will append the input as a directory under `E...001 clients`. Note that the strings are concatenated and the double-quotes are there solely to tell batch "here be a string that may contain spaces."

If this works, and there's no reason why it wouldn't (does for me...) then all you'd need to do is enter the client details and the template would be copied to a new directory. Now actually playing around with the data in the files that are copied so that they are customised - well, at the price, that would be worthy of another question...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo Backing up file
set /P source=Enter source folder:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set /P Folder name=Enter Folder name
set xcopy=xcopy // Set the switches as per your need
%xcopy% %source% %destination%
pause
```